# How do I create a reverse proxy that runs in Azure?

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy

We have a static WordPress website that we would like to be able to scale ad-hoc.

In the long term we will move the site to eg. Umbraco CMS, but right now we would like to put in an Reverse Proxy frontend that takes the load of the current site.

We have tried writing out own HttpHandler (like this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/HTTPReverseProxy.aspx), but we want a more robust solutions that handles caching out of the box,  HTTP redirects (301, 302) etc.

We would like to be able to host this in a standard Azure WebRole, so we can spin up as many roles as needed.... that is, it should be configurable in web.config or by using a small simple startup task (*.cmd file).

Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Application Request Routing (ARR).  Take a look here:

http://things.smarx.com/#Install Application Request Routing

Also watch how Steve configured it as a reverse proxy in his talk from MIX:

http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/SVC04

Comment: I've haven't got this working, because we introduced a static HTML page on our website instead (to be able to server many concurrent users). But the Smarx seams to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at http://smarxrole.codeplex.com, which does this.

Comment: @Steve, could you suggest how to do with latest trends or any whitepapers ?