# Different versions of web app (cloud services) on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant web app running in a Windows Azure cloud service.  Each tenant has their own sub-domain such as tenantA.mysite.com and tenantB.mysite.com.  A global *.mysite.com points them all to my web app.

I need to be able to introduce new versions of my app, and move tenants over a few at a time slowly, while keeping the others on the old version.

Right now I create a new cloud service with the new app, and add a specific DNS record for that tenant to point to the new service.

The problem is the down-time caused by changing DNS records and propagation.

Any recommendations for a way to do this without changing DNS records?

My only thought is to do some type of redirect when they hit the old app, but seems like that would cause delays for every single request - or would it?

Comment: What causes the requirement (justification) to move tenants over a few at a time slowly, while keeping the others on the old version?

Comment: This allows us to put a few "early adopter" customers on the new version of the app, and we can make sure everything is working well before moving other customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trickier than just updating the DNS records for a tenant. The way DNS propagation and caching works, for some users the DNS would resolve to the new location and for other users, at the same time, it would still resolve to the previous location. The result is that you could have users accessing two different deployments for the same tenant at the same time. Even using [Traffic Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh744833.aspx), as you can read in its documentation, you have no direct control over the clients' behavior ("browsers typically cache these entries for longer periods, even after their TTL has expired").

Another approach would be to use a front-end layer with a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) that internally forwards traffic to the appropriate cloud services according to rules you define. Changing these rules on the reverse proxy would affect all incoming requests.

Another way would be to use [feature toggles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle) so that you would run a single cloud service and update it for all tenants (using VIP swap to avoid downtime), but only selected tenants with the new features set as active would see them.

Comment: Right that's the problem with a DNS solution.  We use feature toggle for small feature releases, but in this case it's a major overhaul with new database schema.  So I agree reverse proxy would be the way to do it.  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200222/how-do-i-create-a-reverse-proxy-that-runs-in-azure) looks promising.

Comment: Yes, you can also use nginx on a balanced group of Linux VMs.

Answer (score 0):

One recommendation, based on the answer to my comment question, would be to maintain duplicate services in 2 data centers and use Azure Traffic Manager (or a DNS service like DynDNS) to load balance the services.  When you have an update, roll out to one data center and change the traffic manager settings to point appropriately.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it would have to be some type of DNS related solution.

Comment: Using Traffic Manager would expose the application to the possibility that different users would be using both the new and the old version at the same time (and possibly even working with two different sets of data, depending on the application's architecture). See my [alternative answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17602669/376366).